# Cordova App pictures and layout are stretching in some devices specially Samsung galaxy S4

Tags: android, html, css, angularjs, cordova

I recently build an android application using Cordova, Ionic, and angularJs. And I am running them through Cordova to create the actual app. the main problem is that it works normally and perfect in most of devices such as Samsung Galaxy S3, Samsung Galaxy S6, huawei, and more. But in another hand, when I am trying to run it in Samsung Galaxy S4, or Samsung Note, Or Samsung Grand, the pictures and layout looks stretching too much. I read some suggestion in stackoverflow that suggests to change meta data to `target-densitydpi=medium-dpi` and it doesn't work neither. here is my meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

and This is how it should looks and how it looks in most devices: [image]

and here is how it looks in Galaxy S4, Note, and Grand. :

[image]

and here is my html code for this page, taking onto consideration that all my classes are from Ionic framework.

'>

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 4em;">
        <img src="pictures/bb.png" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class=".col col-33 col-offset-5">
            <a href="" ng-click="checkAuthenticationAndNaviagte()">
                <img src="pictures/icons/coupon6.png" width="75" height="75"/>
            </a>
            <p class="category-title">Coupons</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-33">
            <a href="" ui-sref="offersState">
                <img src="pictures/icons/offers6.png" width="75" height="75" />
            </a>

            <p class="category-title">App Offers</p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-33">
            <a href="" ui-sref="eventsState">
                <img src="pictures/icons/event6.png" width="75" height="75" />
            </a>
            <p class="category-title" >Events</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" >
        <div class=".col col-33 col-offset-5">
            <a ui-sref="RequestCouponState">
                <img src="pictures/icons/member6.png" width="75" height="75" />
            </a>
            <p class="category-title">Membership</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-33">
            <a ui-sref="contactUs">
                <img src="pictures/icons/contact6.png" width="75" height="75"/>
            </a>
            <p class="category-title" >Contact us</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-33">
            <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/BeautyNetPage?ref=br_rs', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
                <img src="pictures/icons/face6.png" width="75" height="75"/>
            </a>
            <p class="category-title">Facebook</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" >

        <div class=".col col-33 col-offset-5">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="pictures/icons/website6.png" onclick="window.open('http://www.beautynet.ps/', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;" width="75" height="75" />
            </a>
            <p class="category-title" >Website</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Any Suggestion guys ??

Comment: hmmm This is odd. How about making your logo and heading an image?

Comment: it's actually a image, my heading is an image.

Comment: How about setting the width of your image a 100% and having your height at a pixel value;

Comment: Also what image type are you using? Some image types tend to be buggy on certain smartphones.

Comment: What do u think best type of picture I should use ?

Comment: Well, first did you try putting the height at a pixel value?

Comment: yes bro, it worked for me. thank you very much. but the icons still close to each other. do u think that I should change the width and height of the icons also ??
btw.  if you want you can assign your solution as an answer, and I will mark it as answered question to earn the reputation. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think you should add margin-left and margin-right to the icons. If that doesnt work, you could also try experimenting with the width and height of the icons.

Comment: you should remove the target-densitydpi from the viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is put the height of the logo image at a pixel value.

Comment: Man thank you so much. The problem was that I am forgetting the "." Before the ".col" because of that it doesn't take the css properly. And your solution helped me to adjust the logo.

Comment: No problem Nadeem, happy to help :)